# PHP -- Check to see if a script it running, loops browser forever

Tags: php, exec

The code:

```
exec('ps aux |grep tweet',$output,$return_var);
if(count($output)>0){
    exec('php ' . DOCROOT . 'gremlins/tweet_gremlin.php &');
    file_put_contents(DOCROOT . 'gremlins/tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Tweet Gremlin was not running. Starting now...');
}
```

In my head, this code makes sense but it just causes the browser to loop indefinitely.  What I'm trying to do is check to see if tweet_gremlin.php is running, if its not running, start it.  DOCROOT is a constant defined earlier in the code.

Comment: The only line that could be causing an infinite loop is the `exec('php' ...)` one. what does that script do?

Comment: Your `if` statement is telling PHP to run `tweet_gremlin.php` only if it's already running.

Comment: @Palladium I think that's only part of it, if the page is "looping indefinitely" it may be because the exec of the php script is waiting for it to finish (which looks like a daemon). If that's the case you may need to do something like `exec('php yourfile.php >> /dev/null 2>&1 &')`. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: @tigrang Could you explain the code you've displayed a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (!exec("ps aux | grep tweet | grep -v grep")) {
    // do something
}
```

The `grep -v` part removes the `grep` process from the list.

Also, to execute a background process with `exec` and such, you will be need to redirect the output, otherwise your script will hang until the process has finished. Per example:

```
exec('php script.php >/dev/null &');
```

Comment: This seems to work but if I put
    exec('php ' . DOCROOT . 'gremlins/tweet_gremlin.php &');

into the loop, the browser loops forever.  Do I need to do some sort of escaping of the ampersand?

Comment: @cwscribner: Because you can't execute background processes that way. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I found was, sometimes when you do `ps -aux | grep "something"` there is always a process. The process is basically your command itself! so try out the commands actually in shell before using them in php.

Comment: +1 bingo... I'd overlooked that myself. You're right, the grep would always find itself. If that code snippet **IS** the tweet_gremlin script, then it'd be invoking itself over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to try

```
if( count($output)==0 )
```

because you want to test if the process is NOT there right?

Answer (score 0):

You or someone could potentially find this useful, its a script Ive written a long time ago

```
<?php
// shut system if wget is not running

function rempty($tbl)
{
    foreach ($tbl as $key => $val)
    {
        if (trim($val) == '')
            unset ($tbl[$key]);
    }

    return $tbl;
}

while (count(rempty(explode("\n",trim(shell_exec('pgrep wget'))))) > 0)
    sleep(1);

echo 'done. shutting down in 30 mins...';
sleep (30*60);
shell_exec('sudo halt');

?>
```